# How best to diagnose these network issues?

Tags: network, monterey

First, let me say that I have two nearly identical laptops running Monterey on the same WiFi network at an Air B&B. This one that I'm typing on, is having zero problems. The other, my work laptop, has had problems for the last day that keep getting worse. It started with complaints that there was some reason why the WiFi password could not be stored in the keychain, coupled with an invitation to reset it.

I've rebooted and tried everything I can think of. Anybody have any suggestions as to how I might diagnose this?

Here are some of the tests I've run:

```
$  ping google.com
ping: cannot resolve google.com: Unknown host

$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
ping: sendto: No route to host
[...]
Request timeout for icmp_seq 25
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 26
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 27
Request timeout for icmp_seq 28
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=29 ttl=110 time=43.013 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=30 ttl=110 time=53.301 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=31 ttl=110 time=48.873 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=32 ttl=110 time=64.942 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=33 ttl=110 time=160.592 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=34 ttl=110 time=72.191 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=35 ttl=110 time=101.511 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=36 ttl=110 time=60.656 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=37 ttl=110 time=56.376 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=38 ttl=110 time=91.075 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=39 ttl=110 time=88.542 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=40 ttl=110 time=43.606 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=41 ttl=110 time=78.460 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=42 ttl=110 time=48.215 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=43 ttl=110 time=72.226 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=44 ttl=110 time=69.680 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=45 ttl=110 time=66.914 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=46 ttl=110 time=61.624 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=47 ttl=110 time=62.591 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=48 ttl=110 time=93.307 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=49 ttl=110 time=48.957 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=50 ttl=110 time=232.135 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51 ttl=110 time=136.539 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
52 packets transmitted, 23 packets received, 55.8% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 43.013/80.666/232.135/42.840 ms

$  host art.net
/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/a0876c02-1788-11ed-b9c4-96898e02b808/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/bind9/bind9/lib/isc/unix/socket.c:2132: internal_send: fe80::c6e5:32ff:feda:b4c6%6#53: Network is down
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$  host google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
$  host google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
$
```

Worth noting: my work machine can see the local WiFi network just fine, and had no problem transferring files to my other computer via Airdrop.

Switching the WiFi to a cell phone hotspot doesn't make difference.

I have GlobalProtect VPN on my machine. It's not connected, but I'm thinking of removing it entirely, but I'll need it later.

---

Next morning:

I uninstalled Globalprotect last night and got the internet working. Our tech support people were able to then re-install Globalprotect and everything was fine. But now, the next morning, it's all broken again.

Primary symptoms:

- Local network is good; `ping MyPersonalMac.local` works fine
- `ping 8.8.8.8 works fine`
- `ping google.com` times out after about a minute with `ping: cannot resolve google.com: Unknown host`
- `host google.com` likewise times out with `;; connection timed out: no servers could be reached`
- My personal laptop connected to the same network has no problems

Certainly seems that my DNS system is borked.

Comment: Did you run `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Network Utility.app` to diagnose the issue?

Comment: `there was some reason why the WiFi password could not be stored in the keychain`... this might actually be a symptom of an underlying cause.  Please add as much information about what happen as you can.

Comment: I'm strongly suspecting the presence of GlobalProtect is related. I uninstalled it, and was able to connect to the internet and start a session with our tech support department. They re-added the latest version of GlobalProtect and all was well. Then it was all broken again this morning. I'll probably have to go into the office in person to get this fixed.

Comment: @nohillside `Network Utility` displays `Network Utility has been deprecated` and has me run "Wireless Diagnostics" insteead.

Comment: Which is also a good place to start :-) looks like I have to update my notes.

Comment: Annnnd "Network Diagnostics" says that DNS is borked. Looks like I'm going into the office today.

Comment: I'm having the same kind of issues on Monterey, but my work system is so locked down, I can't run `Network Utility` or `Wireless Diagnostics` - only root can.  Regardless, I'm starting to wonder if this isn't an issue with Monterey...